# Overlay plots from df.hist()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to overlay plots from a dataframe using:

```
data[target==0].hist(color='b')
data[target==1].hist(color='r')
plt.show()
```

The dataframe has 15 columns each and it produces 30 plots instead of 15 with 2 plots each.

How can I get it to overplot the second set of 15 on the first set of 15?

I can do it with a loop and using subplots but I'm hoping for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the correct number of axes object to pandas `plot()`, otherwise, it will be forced to create a new figure to accomodate the plot you are requesting.

If you want to specify the geometry of your axes yourself:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=0, size=(100,20)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=1, size=(100,20)))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(4,5)
df1.hist(ax=axs)
df2.hist(ax=axs)
```

[image]

Otherwise, if you prefer pandas creating the initial set of subplots by itself:

```
df1.hist(color='b')
df2.hist(color='r', ax=plt.gcf().axes)
```

[image]

Comment: Your second option gives me the error: `ValueError: The number of passed axes must be 15, the same as the output plot` (I edited my question, I have 15 columns)

Comment: @user7867665 : Try the following in the second case: `ax = df1.hist(color='b')` and then `df2.hist(color='r', ax=ax)` and see if it works. I doubt though

Comment: @user7867665 That is probably because your data is different. Unfortunately we do not have your data.

Comment: Okay the first method works for me which is very easy. I approve it as the right answer although the second option doesn't work for me